# How can I tell Gedit which syntax highlighting to apply?

Tags: gedit, syntax-highlighting

For some godforsaken reason, Twig files in our source code are saved with a `.html` extension, instead of a `.twig` extension. I followed [guidelines to add custom highlighting to Gedit](https://askubuntu.com/a/473135), and [the Twig highlighter I found](https://github.com/gabrielcorpse/gedit-twig-template-language/blob/master/twig.lang) does attach to `.html` files (with `<property name="globs">*.twig;*.html;</property>`). However, the inbuilt HTML highlighter *also* attaches to `.html` files (with `<property name="globs">*.html;*.htm</property>`). This is the ruleset that Gedit uses for `.html` files (possibly because `html.lang` is earlier alphabetically than `twig.lang`).

I don’t often edit either HTML or Twig, so I don’t need some sort of automated solution which works out what type of file it *really* is and applies the correct highlighting. Picking the highlighting from a Preferences menu would be sufficient. Is there any way to do that?

Basically, when I open a `.html` file, I want a way to tell Gedit that this file is actually Twig.

Comment: Use a modeline: https://askubuntu.com/a/901057/158442

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can go to

`View -> Highlight mode -> Select which one you need`

Comment: Heh. I was searching under Tools and under Edit → Preferences. Never occurred to me to look at View. Thanks.

Comment: I've actually found that it's also in the status bar at the bottom of the window.